# How Topshelf handled unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception, topshelf

I know there is an event OnException to log the unhandled exception but it could not be able to stop the Topshelf service. As a result, on occurance of unhandled exception, topshelf service stops.

Expected:
In case of unhandled exception, topshelf logs it without the stopping or exiting the topshelf service.

Please help?

```
 var rc = HostFactory.Run(x =>                                   //1
            {
                x.Service<TestService>(s =>
                {                    
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new TestService());
                    s.WhenStarted((tc,hc) => tc.Start(hc));
                    s.WhenStopped((tc,hc) => tc.Stop(hc));     
                });

                x.SetInstanceName("TestService11");

                x.SetDescription("Test Service");                   //7
                x.SetDisplayName("TestService 11");                                  //8
                x.SetServiceName("TestService11");
                x.RunAs(".\administrator", "passwor123");

                x.StartAutomatically(); 

                x.UseLog4Net();

                x.UnhandledExceptionPolicy = UnhandledExceptionPolicyCode.LogErrorOnly;                

                x.EnableServiceRecovery(r =>
                {
                    // Has no corresponding setting in the Recovery dialogue.
                    // OnCrashOnly means the service will not restart if the application returns
                    // a non-zero exit code.  By convention, an exit code of zero means ‘success’.
                    r.OnCrashOnly();
                    // Corresponds to ‘First failure: Restart the Service’
                    // Note: 0 minutes delay means restart immediately
                    r.RestartService(0);
                    // Corresponds to ‘Second failure: Restart the Service’
                    // Note: TopShelf will configure a 1 minute delay before this restart, but the
                    // Recovery dialogue only shows the first restart delay (0 minutes)
                    r.RestartService(1);
                    // Corresponds to ‘Subsequent failures: Restart the Service’
                    r.RestartService(2);
                    // Corresponds to ‘Reset fail count after: 1 days’
                    r.SetResetPeriod(1);
                });

                x.OnException((ex) =>
                {
                    HostLogger.Get<TestService>().Info("Exception occured Main : " + ex.ToString());
                });


            });
```

Comment: After an exception occurs, your service is in an undefined state. Why do you want it to _continue_ from there, rather than _restart_?

Comment: I have multiple threads in the application, if any thread throws unhandled exception, it should not affect other thread execution. I think, it's not good idea to restart service on occurance of single thread's exception. I know, we should put try..catch within thread execution but somehow, I want to centralized it to log and thread abortion in topshelf.

Comment: I'm with @CodeCaster on this one. If your Service has three independent processes, then they should be 3 separate services, or 3 hosted services in an app. If you BADLY want to do these in the same Service, I would wrap the Task.Run (or whatever triggers your multiple threads) in individual try blocks.